# Getting data from Multiple Item ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get data froma Multiple Item listview but I keep getting errors when I try the get on onListItemClick.

It seems to be asking me to create methods when:

```
i.putExtra("title", this.getItem(position).getTitle());
```

is called.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
    Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = new Vector<RowData>();
    for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
    try {
        rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
       data.add(rd);
    }
       CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, R.id.title, data);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
       getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }


         public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {   


               Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowDetails.class);
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               i.putExtra("title", this.getItem(position).getTitle());
               i.putExtra("title", this.getItem(position).getDetail());
               setResult(ShowDetails.RESULT_OK, i);
               finish();
        }


 private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                        int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               
 super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
      @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
       ViewHolder holder = null;
       TextView title = null;
       TextView detail = null;
       ImageView i11=null;
       RowData rowData= getItem(position);
       if(null == convertView){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
 }
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             title = holder.gettitle();
             title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
             detail = holder.getdetail();
             detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);                                                     
             i11=holder.getImage();
             i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
             return convertView;
}
            private class ViewHolder {
            private View mRow;
            private TextView title = null;
            private TextView detail = null;
            private ImageView i11=null; 
            public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
 }
         public TextView gettitle() {
             if(null == title){
                 title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                }
            return title;
         }     
         public TextView getdetail() {
             if(null == detail){
                  detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
                    }
           return detail;
         }
        public ImageView getImage() {
             if(null == i11){
                  i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
                                      }
                return i11;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: It's asking me to create a method for getTitle... when I alreayd have one.  `i.putExtra("title", this.getItem(position).getTitle());`

Comment: you should do String title = this.getItem(position).getTitle(); and try that.

Comment: Did that... that gives me an error and wants me to create a method for getItem then.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have the gettitle() method and not the getTitle() defined in your adapter.

The getTitle() is a method of the adapter. The getItem(position) return an object of type RowData, which has not such a method.

Moreover the getTitle() returns a TextView. Are you sure you want to pass a TextView via an Intent or the String of this TextView?

Comment: Yes.... I'm trying to bundle the (title & detail) of the item selected and send them to a new activity.

Comment: I figured it out... I had to get the title & detail this way.

`Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowDetails.class);
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           i.putExtra("title", this.getItem(position).getTitle());
           i.putExtra("detail", this.getItem(position).getDetail());
           setResult(ShowDetails.RESULT_OK, i);
           finish();`